# how to get the total number of retweets of my account?

Tags: twitter

looks like there is a method that gives the retweets of a particular tweet.  IS there any way to find out the total number of all retweets of my tweets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. There may be a few hacks to get an approximation, but the answer is still no.

Twitter urges developers to think of timelines as an infinite stream rather than a finite list of tweets. You cannot count something when it has infinite length, so you cannot get the total number of retweets.

What you can do is take a small piece of the timeline (1000 tweets?) and say "I was retweeted 200 times in my past 1000 tweets".

When developing Twitter applications, always take this into consideration. **There's no such thing as "all tweets", just the last x.**